# Putting ASP.NET MVC into a WebForms page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any way to render a normal view of asp.net MVC action onto an old `.aspx` WebForm using an MVC helper or some other method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: The proposed solution below is a hack.

Suppose that you have the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and a corresponding partial (`Foo.ascx`).

And now in a legacy WebForms page you wanted to use this action. Here's how you could proceed:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    private class DummyController : Controller { }

    public HtmlHelper Html { get; private set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(
            httpContext, 
            new RouteData(), 
            new DummyController()
        );
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            controllerContext, 
            new WebFormView("Views"), 
            new ViewDataDictionary(), 
            new TempDataDictionary(), 
            TextWriter.Null
        );
        Html = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, new ViewPage());  
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%= Html.Action("About", "Home") %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be updated to use Html.RenderAction(actionName, controllerName) or Html.RenderPartial("someView.ascx", viewModel)

Comment: +1 Works for me in MVC3, I needed to pass in the `controllerContext` to the `WebFormView` constructor to get it to compile though.

Comment: To get `RenderAction` to work, do steps above, and change `TextWriter.Null` to `Response.Output` and change `<%=` to `<%` .

Answer (score 2):

I used this code in my MasterPage and it worked. But after days I have found that my application was restarting every minute because of memory leaks. I was hunting days for the cause and finnally, this part of code was the cause of memory leak. You have to dispose DummyController and ViewPage. I have fix it like this:

```
 public class BaseMaster :  System.Web.UI.MasterPage
 {

#region MVC
    Controller _controller= new DummyController();
    ViewPage _viewPage = new ViewPage();

    private class DummyController : Controller { }

    public HtmlHelper Html { get; private set; }

    private void InitHtmlHelper()
    {          
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(
            httpContext,
            new RouteData(),
            _controller
        );
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            controllerContext,
            new WebFormView(controllerContext,"Views"),
            new ViewDataDictionary(),
            new TempDataDictionary(),
            TextWriter.Null
        );
        Html = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, _viewPage);  
    }


    public override void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();

        _controller.Dispose();
        _viewPage.Dispose();
    }

#endregion


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            InitHtmlHelper();
            ...
            ...
        }

        ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be using client-side scripting. For example using [`jQuery.Load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)